# How define in-line or within alert function, that is define mostly separate function in flex?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flash-builder

I want to define inline function within alert class currently i have following implementation.

```
Alert.show('my mesage', 'header message', Alert.OK, Alert.No, doAction)

private function doAction(event:CloseEvent):void
{
    //some code
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean you want to do this? (Extremely bad idea):

```
Alert.show('my mesage', 'header message', Alert.OK, Alert.No, function(event:CloseEvent):void
{
    //some code
});
```